# SQL - find records where id doesn't exist in / have ANY

Tags: sql, ms-access

SQL - find records where a owner dont have ANY rental car.
I've got the following (in MS Access):

```
Car_Owner
+----+------+---------+--------+
| id | name | Car reg | Rental |
+----+------+---------+--------+
| 1  | Adam | ABC123  |  True  | 
+----+------+---------+--------+
| 2  | John | XXX111  |  True  | 
+----+------+---------+--------+
| 2  | John | XXX222  |  False | //Same person as above
+----+------+---------+--------+
| 3  | Eva  | YYY999  |  False | 
+----+------+---------+--------+
```

How do I find out who dosn't rent ANY car? In this case would be just Eva. John should not be listed since he already got a rental car.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One method uses aggregation:

```
select name
from car_owner
group by name
having sum(iif(rental, 1, 0)) = 0;
```

You can also check that the value is always false by doing:

```
having max(rental) = 0 and min(rental) = 0
```

Comment: Thanks that worked :) BTW how can I use "select count(id)" ? Simply putting a "count" gives me wrong values which confusing.

Comment: @Nyprez . . . Your comment does not seem related to the question or answer, because neither have `count()` in them.  I suggest that you ask another question.

Comment: No worries I solved it :) I was just curious that's why I asked, but it had nothing to do with my real question so that's why I didn't mentioned it.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select * from Car_Owner 
 Where Rental = False
   and Id Not In
      (Select Id from Car_Owner Where Rental = True)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from car_owner
where name not in (select name from car_owner where rental = True);
```

Answer (score 1):

Below SQL may help you out too:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Car_Owner
WHERE   Rental = False
        AND id NOT IN ( SELECT  id
                        FROM    Car_Owner
                        WHERE   Rental = True )
```

OR

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Car_Owner a
WHERE   Rental = False
        AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT id
                         FROM   Car_Owner b
                         WHERE  b.Rental = True
                                AND b.id = a.id )
```

Comment: Thanks! The second solution was interesting.